# Data transfer from mysql to DynamoDB

Tags: django, boto, amazon-dynamodb

I want to transfer data(21M rows) from mysql database to DynamoDB. I am using boto Python API and django 1.3.1 to export data from mysql and transfer it to DynamoDB. Below is the code:

```
      conn = boto.connect_dynamodb()
      start_date = datetime.date(2012, 3, 1)
      end_date = datetime.date(2012, 3, 31)
      episode_report = TableName.objects.filter(viewdt__range=(start_date, end_date))
      #Paginate 21 million rows in chunks of 1000 each
      p = Paginator(episode_report, 1000)
      table = conn.get_table('ep_march')
      for page in range(1, p.num_pages + 1): 
          for items in p.page(page).object_list:
              item_data = {
                        'id': int(items.id),
                        'user_id': format_user(items.user),     #Foreign Key to User table
                        'episode_id': int(items.episode.id),          #Foreign Key to Episode table
                        'series_id': int(items.series.id),      #Foreign Key to Series Table
                        'viewdt': str(items.viewdt),                   
                     }
              item = table.new_item(
                                    # Our hash key is 'id'
                                    hash_key= int(items.id),
                                    # Our range key is 'viewdt'
                                    range_key= str(items.viewdt),
                                    # This has the
                                    attrs=item_data
                                )
              item.put()
```

The issue is that the process has been running for more than 12 hours and has still transferred 3M rows. Any ideas to speed up the process?

I would create more threads and parellize the transfer and see if that helps.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, what is the provisioned throughput of your DynamoDB table?  That will ultimately control how many writes/second you can make.  Adjust accordingly.

Second, get some sort of concurrency going.  You could use threads (make sure each thread has it's own connection object because httplib.py is not threadsafe) or you could use gevent or multiprocess or whatever mechanism you like but concurrency is key.

Comment: Thanks, I jacked up the Provisioned Write Throughput to 400, but its not helping. I would use concurrency and run the transfer again.

Comment: I tried using concurrency, however it is not of much help. I am using a m1.large EC2 instance which is running django1.3. I am thinking of exporting data from mysql to S3 and then use EMR to export data from S3 to DynamoDB. Thoughts?

Comment: Okay, if you have the table provisioned for 400 writes/second and you have 21 million rows, theoretically that could complete in about 14.5 hours.  However, that assumes that each record is at most 1K bytes.  That's what the 400 means; 400 writes of 1K in size or smaller.  How big are your items?

Comment: Each record is of 1048 bytes. Actually the Write Throughput is not the bottleneck, Consumed Write Cap shows 90.023. I was able to transfer 1M rows in 3hrs using multiple threads with CPU Util around 120%. I would probably launch 22 EC2 instances and run the transfer using the cluster.

Answer (score 2):

Amazon's solution for bulk data transfers into and out of DynamoDB is to use Elastic MapReduce. Here are the docs: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/EMRforDynamoDB.html